# Bootstrap Modal shows but no text is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

So I'm having quite a hard time figuring out why my text does not show in my bootstrap modal. I've tested, and it *appears* that only text wrapped in header tags are shown. Unwrapped text and text wrapped in paragraph tags do not show. I am truly baffled. The modal body and background show perfectly, so it is not a javascript issue. My code is below. This modal uses some Angular, but again, anything wrapped in a header tag works...I'm wondering if I left something out that Bootstrap requires in order to display *ordinary* text. I'm using Bootstrap v2.3.2.

```
<div id="column-select-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1"    role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" ng-blur="show=false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="show=false"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel1">Adjust Data Columns</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="height:250px;">
        <div class="fixedOverflowTable250">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-text-color swap-goal-modal-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="checkbox-align2 nogo text-align-left" style="width:73%;">
                            <h4>Column Name</h4>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-ng-repeat="(key, value) in list">
                    <tr class="parent">
                        <td class="checkbox-align2 text-align-left">
                            <h5>{{key}}</h5>  <p>THIS DOES NOT SHOW</p> THIS DOESN'T EITHER
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
       <!--  <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-error" ng-show="columnError">{{columnError}}</div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="selectColumns(selectedColumns)">Apply</button>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="show=false">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also insured that the other classes I use aren't screwing around with my CSS. I've included a screenshot link to show as well. Thanks in advance for your help!
http://screencloud.net/v/bD79

Comment: I think it could be something in your list, check your angular app, as your modal is shown. Try to print something outside the ng-repeat, or create a row with some that and then do the repeat. Do you get your 'list' values in the console ?

Comment: All the items from the list show as long as they are wrapped in header tags.

Comment: I believe I just discovered what the issue actually is. It's not in my modal. It's in some styling far outside my modal. I believe there is a `<div>` that has the btn-group class added to it outside of my current html. This modal is being included via a directive. I'm going to experiment and get back to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I just discovered the issue. My unwrapped, *ordinary* text does not show because my modal is being included in a directive, and that directive happens to be inside a `<div class="btn-group">`. Apparently that's hiding the *ordinary* text. I didn't realize this because the `<div>` is outside of my current working code. So this may be a simple error in reality, but apparently unwrapped text does not show inside of an element with Bootstrap btn-group in its class.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution, it definitely saved me some time :) I had mine in header and that also causes the same problem.

Comment: You saved my million of year dear.. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is small mistake you have just added hide class at first div which was not displaying div content find below code what you have added

```
<div id="column-select-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1"    role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" ng-blur="show=false">
```

use below one

```
<div id="column-select-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"    role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" ng-blur="show=false">
```

remove hide class from this div it will work fine.